# Updating speed only after button tapped in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, distance, cllocation

I'm making an app that measures speed and distance in real time. so before did that app starts updating location when button tapped. but this method takes time after button tapped. if i will put locationManager.startUpdatingLocation in viewDidLoad, speed and distance starts measure immediately without tapping start button. How can I do like speed and distance starts measure immediately ONLY WHEN when start button tapped? here's my code.

```
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
 @IBAction func startStopButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        if isStarted { //When tapped STOP
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        startStopButton.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
    } else { //When tapped START
        startStopButton.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
    }
  }
    
    func locationManager (_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {
    let location = locations[0]
    speedLabel.text = "\(Int(location.speed * 3.6))"
        
        if (startLocation == nil) {
    startLocation = location;
     }
     let endLocation = location;

    let distance = startLocation.distance(from: endLocation) / 1000 //m->km
    distanceLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", distance)) km"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you, but why don't you just `startUpdatingLocation` where you handle the start button tap?

Comment: If i will do this it will take some time to get location. app should immediately get location when user open it. but in Screen, speed and distance should equal 0 until user taps start button.

Comment: updating the location,. and recording speed are two different things - as @kyers suggests, start updating the location as soon as the app opens, but use the button to set a flag, and within didUpdateLocations, only update the speed if the flag has been set

Comment: Check my answer, and try it out. It might need a few tweaks, but the idea should work.

Comment: Everything works when tapping start button at the first time. But after tapping reset than start again speed and distance doesn't work. looks like you're missed var isToCalc.... = False in viewController. I also tryed to add isToPerformCalculations = false to reset and stop function but it doesn't work

Comment: I fixed some places in code and now everything works exactly how I want Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you might use an extra variable to make sure that when you are getting the location on app start, the speed and distance calculations should not be done. Something like this:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        isToPerformCalculations = false
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
 @IBAction func startStopButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
     if isStarted { //When tapped STOP
       // locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        startStopButton.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
    } else { //When tapped START
        isToPerformCalculations = true
        startStopButton.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
    }
  }
    
    func locationManager (_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {
    let location = locations[0]
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if isToPerformCalculations {
        if (startLocation == nil) {
           startLocation = location;
        }
        let endLocation = location;

    
         speedLabel.text = "\(Int(location.speed * 3.6))"
         let distance = startLocation.distance(from: endLocation) / 1000 //m->km
         distanceLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", distance)) km"
    }
}
```

I also changed where you `stopUpdatingLocation`, see if this works for you.

Comment: Like I told you, the idea of using the flag should work, but to achieve your result you might have to tweak a few things. If the solution worked, please accept it as the correct answer. Glad I could help.